SUR estimated by OLS: restricted model has higher likelihood
I have three versions of a system of linear regression models: M, M0 and M00. I think each of them is an example of seemingly unrelated regression (SUR). The models are nested: M contains M0, and the latter contains M00. I am interested in testing the validity of the (exclusion/null) restrictions on M0 that turn it into M00. I have considered using a likelihood ratio (LR) test for that.
I am implementing this in R using the systemfit package. First I define the system of equations (eqSystem) for M and the restriction matrices (Rmat0 and Rmat00) and vectors (qvec0 and qvec00) for obtaining M0 and M00 from M. Then I estimate M0 and M00 and try running the LR test:
M0  <- systemfit(formula=eqSystem, method="OLS", restrict.matrix=Rmat0 , restrict.rhs=qvec0 )  
M00 <- systemfit(formula=eqSystem, method="OLS", restrict.matrix=Rmat00, restrict.rhs=qvec00)
lrtest(M00, M0)

There is no problem with estimating the models, but the LR test result is followed by the following warning:
Warning message:
In lrtest.systemfit(M00, M0) :
  model '2' has a smaller log-likelihood value than the more restricted model '1'

I wonder how that is possible. After all M00 is a submodel of M0, so its maximized likelihood cannot be higher. I suspect the answer has to do with how the models are specified and estimated in the systemfit package. Perhaps method="OLS" does not coincide with maximization of the likelihoods used in the LR test? (Update: @jbowman indicates in a comment that this is indeed the case.)
At first I thought of posting a coding-focused question on Stack Overflow, but for that I need a minimal reproducible example. However, I would like to avoid sharing my data. So then I thought I could create a simulated dataset that would produce the behavior above. But for that of course I must understand what is going on! Thus I find myself in a vicious circle.
Could you please help me figure out what is going on? I think it would be instructive to present a minimal example that reproduces the behavior.

is this a nonconvexity problem? What happens if you initialize M0 at the solution given by M00 (i.e. using the "startvals" parameter)? What if you do the opposite? What if you try 1000 random initialization for each, and then compare the two solutions with best likelihood in each model class?

Does the raw data have NAs?  I've seen this warnikg before but forget if it occurs when models are fit to different datasets because a predictor has NAs

@NBrower, there are no NAs.

@JohnMadden, can I even initialize anything here? The fitting is by OLS. (I will check this in more detail when I am back to my laptop.)

OLS does not correspond to MLE in a system of equations with nonzero correlation of the errors across equations unless all the regressors in the equations are the same.  Try method = "SUR" and see what happens.

@jbowman, does this depend on the model for which the likelihood is being maximized? E.g. if the model assumes the errors are uncorrelated across equations, would the OLS and MLE coincide? And when the assumption is relaxed, they would not coincide anymore? So my warning could be explained by the model behind MLE not coinciding with the model that is "implied" by OLS? (I stick to OLS instead of SUR because I worry about inexact estimates of the weighting matrix due to a smallish sample. I feel that OLS may be safer than GLS here.)

@jbowman, It would be very interesting to see a minimal example illustrating the point. Like 2 equations, a single X, M is unrestricted, M0 contains one zero restriction, M00 contains two zero restrictions, would that be enough? If so, how should this model be parameterized to achieve the "paradox"? Certainly, for many sets of parameter values, the more restricted model would deliver the lower likelihood. What knob in the model should we twist to produce the "paradox"?

@jbowman, for practical purposes, I am looking for how to test M0 against M00. If lrtest should not be applied given my use of method="OLS", then could linearHypothesis work? My impression was I could use it for comparing a full model such as M to a submodel (either M0 or M00) but not a submodel such as M0 to a subsubmodel M00. Am I wrong? Would it be possible to use linearHypothesis in my case?

All excellent questions.  The answers to your first set are yes and yes, respectively - OLS = MLE implies that errors are uncorrelated across equations (except for identical regressors).  If the test doesn't make that assumption, you have a mismatch, which would likely (ha ha) be irrelevant if the correlations were small but not so if the correlations were "substantial", whatever that is.  I can certainly understand your concern about covariance estimation with small samples, but then you should perhaps construct your own test outside of systemfit...

linearHypothesis also uses the estimated covariance matrix, so it is not helpful if you assume it's diagonal.  You could just calculate the log-likelihoods for each of the equations and sum them together, then compare that to the summed log-likelihoods for the restricted equations, it seems to me.  I may try to construct an example since this is an interesting issue.

richard: john fox is very responsive on the R-list and he wrote linearHypothesis ( assuming that you are referring to the car package )  so if you rephrase your question and just deal with linearHypothesis, he may able to help you. Of course, I can't speak for him but it's a good guess. Arnie Henningsen ( author of systemfit ) is also quite generous but I don't know if he's on the R-list. He's another option. Both are very kind people.

@jbowman, great comments! Manual calculation of the likelihood makes sense under the assumption of diagonality. However, I do not necessarily believe the covariances are small; I do not want to rely on that assumption. So if I use method="OLS", I should follow that up by a heteroskedasticity-robust variance matrix, right? And then a Wald test? How to do that with systemfit? Also, I have a vague impression that GMM might be a more flexible method that more naturally allows for an arbitrary weighting matrix. However, I have never tried it in R for a system of equations, so I am hesitant...

What if you stacked your regressions so you have one target variable and a right hand side matrix that's got the individual equaion right hand sides as diagonal blocks?  Then you'd have one equation and GMM might work for that, plus you could use the HAC robust errors more easily.

@jbowman, that is a possibility. It is not elegant (not really a solution I would feel great about sharing with my students; this is for a class) and the HAC part would be complicated by the cluster-like structure. I should probably just try system GMM and pray I would not spend a week or more trying to code it properly; it does not help that my econometric knowledge is getting rusty. I went for systemfit hoping it would be simpler than system GMM. Do you see a way there with a HC robust variance matrix and a Wald test? Could that be implemented with systemfit?

I can't see how to integrate an external covariance matrix estimate or estimation procedure with systemfit other than by copying the systemfit function and rewriting it slightly.  There is a place in the rather lengthy code in an if (method == "OLS") { block where there's a call to a C function that calculates the covariance matrix: rcov <- .calcResidCov(resids, methodResidCov = control$methodResidCov, and the next few lines, which you could substitute a different function for.  I've done that sort of thing before, it's a pain, but it can work.  Maybe that would help you?

@jbowman, thank you, that is worth considering. If you summarize your comments in an answer, I will be happy to upvote it. I will probably get back to this comment thread as I try implementing a solution (whichever one I choose). Or maybe I will have to post a new question with a new problem. Thank you so much for your help so far! It really helped me get unstuck and advanced my understanding of the relevant topics.
